# A word / term for people who criticize others' behavior while exempting themselves from the same criticism

Tags: meaning, word-choice

During gym class, we were doing a workout video. This is what happened:

Two girls start screaming at someone to keep their back straight. The thing is that they are not even keeping their backs straight.

It's really frustrating how they assume that they're doing all the exercises properly and that they can give criticism to other people.

Also, they screamed it out loud exactly when the teacher was coming around.

Is there a word to explain this type of behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when a person criticizes somebody for not adhering to a standard, or value, or form of conduct, but that person himself / herself does not adhere to that standard, value or conduct, that would be called **hypocrisy**.

In this case, as the critics timed their criticism to coincide with the arrival of the teacher, you can add the word **grandstanding**.

If colloquial terms, if I had been in that class and witnessed what you did, I would have referred to the critics as **obnoxious, ass-kissing hypocrites**.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but there's an 'e' in hypocrites.

>hypocrite
/ˈhɪpəkrɪt/
noun
plural noun: hypocrites
a hypocritical person.
"the story tells of respectable Ben who turns out to be a cheat and a hypocrite"
synonyms: sanctimonious person, pietist, whited sepulchre, plaster saint, humbug, pretender, deceiver, dissembler, impostor;

Comment: Thank you, @Dick_Knipple. I appreciate the correction.

Comment: A citation or two would have been nice.

Comment: Didn't expect an answer that fast. Thanks!